# StaleElementReferenceException after Clicking an element

Tags: c#, selenium

Here is the code:

```
IDiv div = page.Div(Find.ByName("xxxx"));
ILink link = div.Link(Find.ByHref("yyyy"));
link.Click();

ISpan span = link.Span(Find.ByText("zzzz"));//StaleElementReferenceException
```

I've been searching for some possible solutions and reason for this exception (due to DOM changing). But, I cannot find a solution for it. Most solutions were to use a try and catch, but that would be for a case where you cannot click the link. My problem is that AFTER clicking the link, the reference to the link is gone. I saw some solutions mentioning something about cache, but not very clear about it.
Any ideas?

Comment: what if you refind it after the `Click()` call: `link = div.Link(Find.ByHref("yyyy"));`?

Comment: I already tried that. But I am trying to look for a better solution as I have many similar test cases.

Comment: I'm not a C# guy, but you should be using a ExpectedCondition with a wait so that Selenium will wait for up to a certain amount of seconds for the weather conditions to be just right.

Comment: So do refinding the element work? It should do, and it's the "right" way to be dealing with stale references. Selenium has to be given a reference to a DOM element it can keep, and when lost it needs to be given that back again.